# PHP if MySQL column = 1 print, else print something else

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

**strong text**I don't know if the title was clear or not,

but I want a PHP script that tells if a MySQL column has data, and if it **does to print** a line of text, but if it is **NULL**, to print something else...

Make sense?

Here is what I have, I know it is completely wrong...

```
$link = mysql_connect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD);
mysql_select_db($DBNAME); 
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     if($row['VIP'] = '1')
     {
        echo('VIP');
     }
     else
     {
        echo('Non-VIP');
     }
}
```

**EDIT::**

Here is the full code:

```
<?php

$DBTYPE = 'mysql';
$DBHOST = 'host';
$DBUSER = 'username';
$DBPASSWORD = 'password';
$DBNAME = 'database';

$link = mysql_connect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD);
mysql_select_db($DBNAME); 
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$member_id= '5'; // get value of the member, assumed that you have post the data into id. change if it is different into your code

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members where id=$member_id");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     if($row['VIP'] == '1')
     {
        echo "<img src='../images/VIP.png' />";
     }
     else
     {
        echo 'Non-VIP';
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: Seems close. You have a syntax error with a missing `}`

Comment: I added the syntax, doesn't work still.

Comment: view my updates into my answer below and try that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use == to check equality, like this:

```
if($row['VIP'] == '1')
{
  echo('VIP');
}
else
{
 echo('Non-VIP');
}
```

**EDIT**

Use below code to get your desired result

```
$link = mysql_connect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD);
mysql_select_db($DBNAME); 
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$member_id=$_POST['id']; // get value of the member, assumed that you have post the data into id. change if it is different into your code

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members where id=$member_id");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     if($row['VIP'] == '1')
     {
        echo "<img src='../images/VIP.png' />";
     }
     else
     {
        echo 'Non-VIP';
     }
}
```

Comment: All that does is print

Non-VIPNon-VIPNon-VIPVIP

On all user pages.

Comment: @Tesoooooo what data you have into your members table for VIP column? and the result you have shown here is after applying my solution?

Comment: If they are VIP the column is 1, if they aren't it is NULL

And yes.

Comment: it prints Non-VIPNon-VIPNon-VIPVIP, because you are doing a `while` loop, so this is telling you that you have 3 rows that are NULL, and 1 row that is 1.

Comment: I removed the while and just made it $row = || 

Now nothing shows up.

Comment: @Tesoooooo yes, Sean is correct you got your desire result, now you just to put image instead of echo it. that's it.

Comment: you have to write while loop if you want to display all members data or if you want to display it for any specific member then you have to add where clause into query like this, select * from members where id=1

Comment: @pkachhia I think you mean - `"SELECT * FROM members where  id=$member_id"` not `"SELECT * FROM members where id=$id"`.

Comment: That didn't work, I even tried changing it to $member_id= "MY_ID"; and it still did nothing.

Comment: no I think you have made some mistakes, how your MY_ID got the value? Have you assigned it or it comes from any other page? Please make it clear, because you are very near to your solution.

Comment: My user ID is 5, I put $member_id = "5"; and it still didn't display the VIP image.

Comment: can you please update your question by adding some detailed code?

Comment: It seems ok, please do one thing, echo your query, copy it and past it into mysql and see what the result?

Comment: echo mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members where id=5"); ?

Comment: no dear, echo "SELECT * FROM members where id=$member_id"; and copy the result and paste it into mysql, and show what it the reult

Comment: I figured it out, I changed id to userid, and then it worked :3, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members");

   if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) // or you can check for 1 too

    {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    // your text output here
    //echo VIP or whatever
    }
    else { echo "non-vip"; }
```

Comment: what do u want to print exactly ? can we have your table and requirement here

Comment: If they are VIP I want to print <img src='../images/VIP.png' />

If they aren't I want to print "Regular User"

My table is char(1) and if they are VIP the data is 1, if not the data is NULL.

Comment: store two values as 1 for VIP and 2 or whatever for non-vip members. and u can check them and print as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show if a user is a `VIP` or `Regular User`. If so, you need to modify your `SELECT` to get the users row, not every row.

```
$id = ...; //logged in user id [ie. $loggedin->id, $_SESSION['id'], etc]

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = $id");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

 if($row['VIP'] == '1')
 {
    echo('VIP');
 }
 else
 {
    echo('Non-VIP');
 }
 }
```

Be aware that you should not write new code using `mysql` functions. You should learn to use [mysqli or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)